# Not able to binding the steps in specflow. Every time getting popup - "Step bindings are still being analyzed. Please wait"

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, bdd, specflow

I am getting the popup "Step bindings are still being analyzed. Please wait" while trying to bind the steps from the feature file. I tried clearing cache, removing temp files, upgrading version of specflow and restarting system and Visual studio but anything did not help. I tried other solution on stackoverflow but I still having the same issue from last 2-3 days.
Looking forward to the solution.

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` folder located in the same directory as the solution file. The .vs folder contains a bunch of temp files too.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is your code has poor performance and that cause the slowness and hangs your Visual Studio or due to low performance of code Visual studio moves in unresponsive state.

The solution is improve the performance of your code. You need to optimize your code in all the possible ways:

- Avoid unnecessary loops
  -Use less parameters in your parametrized methods
  -Use less inputs in each step
  -Divide the number parameters into more methods if taking more than 5 parameters. It will improve the performance.
  -Divide the input values into more sub-step or separate steps, it will improve the performance and speed of the code.
  -Use switch case instead of if else statements if there are more cases.
  -Free up the occupied memory if the reference variables or objects are no more of use.
  -Read data from external sources and store them into objects or lists locally and minimize make it one time read from external source once and access the values copied locally in the lists or any other objects/variables.
  -Close or quite the external files or call to them after use.

Hope this is the best way to improve the performance of code and this issue will no more persist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Deveroom](https://github.com/specsolutions/deveroom-visualstudio) extension for SpecFlow instead of the SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2017/2019. That uses a different technology to discover the bindings and therefore more fast/robost from this perspective. The feature set is about the same and both are free/open source. See https://github.com/specsolutions/deveroom-visualstudio/wiki/Installation for setup instructions.